# Fatal: could not read from remote repository on npm install new dependency

Tags: git, github, npm

After having developed my app for some time, I have lost the local files. I decided to clone them from my remote repo and try to work on them, however, as I still need to implement some ideas, I wanted to install new packaged for my project.
The first npm install of all packages already presents in node_modules went well and without any problem. But if I try to add new ones (for example now I would like to implement VX charts) it gives me this error:

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! exited with error code: 128
```

As I am the actual owner of this repo, I have pretty much no idea what went wrong. By the way, my git user.name and email are configured.

Comment: Do you have a public key? Does the public key has been configured for the repository?

Comment: I did not have it, however after having it configured (the ssh-add -l command gives me an expected result) this did not resolve my issue

Comment: And you get the same error?

Comment: And it has been added to my github account settings as well, @muecas

Comment: Yes, exactly the same one

Comment: What is the url of the repo?

Comment: https://github.com/daria-marczak/weather-app Here you go

Comment: Let me know if it worked.